# Update 4,000+ rows of MySQL database with same integer

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a table "table_blah" which has thousands of rows. I need to update a column "column_blah" with the value "0" in each row.

How can this be done?

Also, I know that a script which executes that many queries in such a short space of time could possibly crash the server. How do I make sure this will not happen?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Worry about crashing the server when you have billions of rows,thousands is nothing for a db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_blah
SET    column_blah = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could you possibly post the full code? Connecting to the database etc.